# Name for homotopy totalization of Goodwillie tower (in embedding calculus)

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, knot-theory, terminology, embeddings

Let $M,N$ be a manifold and consider the presheaf of spaces $\textrm{Emb}(-, N)$ on the open sets of $M$. Classical embedding calculus produces a goodwillie tower
$$ \ldots \rightarrow T_{k+1} \textrm{Emb}(M, N) \rightarrow  T_k \textrm{Emb}(M,N) \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow T_0 \textrm{Emb}(M,N) $$
and the homotopy limit of such tower is usually denoted by $T_{\infty}\textrm{Emb}(M,N)$. In case $\dim N > \dim M + 2$ it is shown to be homotopy equivalent to $\textrm{Emb}(M,N)$, but for smaller codimension they are usually different.

> Does $T_{\infty} \textrm{Emb}(M,N)$ has a "common" name, that is not in formal notation? Maybe "finitary" embeddings? I am particularly interested in the case of knots $M= S^1, N= \mathbb{R}^3$.

I need this for a title and I don't want to mess up with weird notation from the beginning. There will be time in the article to puzzle the reader.

Comment: If there is nothing satisfactory, I could also just go for "an approximation"...

Comment: I might call the functor $T_\infty Emb(-,N)$ the completion of the functor $Emb(-,N)$. (Also, I might call the tower the Weiss tower.)

Comment: I call it the "limit of the embedding calculus tower".

Comment: I am fond of "Goodwillie completion" for the the analog in Goodwillie calculus, so if you wanted a snappy name for the manifold calculus variant either "Weiss completion" or "Goodwillie-Weiss completion" would be my vote.

Comment: Dear @TomGoodWillie, it's an honour to receive the answer from you in this matter! :D thank you all for the suggestions, I find 'completion' to be a nice word. Maybe I would like 'profinite completion' more, because one get this from "finite-degree" approximations and then take the limit. Also, completion could be confused with group completion in case one has a $\mathbb{E}_1$ structure as it happens in knots. But profinite maybe hints at some precise meaning that does not exist. What do you think? Update: "Goodwillie -Weiss completion" probably answers to my concern, didn't see that.